# SP2013 won't use Kerberos - but C2WTSTest passes fine?

Tags: 2013, authentication, kerberos

I'm setting up a new SharePoint 2013 farm using Kerberos authentication. I've read a ton of resources about it and it seems I've got my solution 99% right - Kerberos is working like a charm when I check it with [C2WTSTest.exe](http://rodneyviana.codeplex.com/releases/view/19103), a tool for testing Kerberos on different identities.

The problem I have is actually getting SharePoint 2013 to use Kerberos - everything I see is NTLM, no Kerberos in sight for miles away.

Here's what I checked:

- Kerberos is definitely selected for the web app in question
- The App Pool runs on the correct account
- C2WTS is fully configured, working fine in C2WTSTest.exe
- Authentication Providers in IIS are okay: negotiate over NTLM and Kernel Mode auth is disabled
- Nothing Kerberos-related in Fiddler
- Only my TGT in klist

I've done a ton of reboots (literally restarting the server, not just iisreset) to no avail.

What else can I check, what might be a cause for this?

Comment: If you don't see a Kerberos ticket with klist for the resource (URL) you're accessing double check your SPN / URL / app pool account combination. If that's ok, double check if SharePoint is configured for Kerberos in web app authentication settings. Start with the basics. The c2wts will only be used when doing delegation, not for authentication to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I have the following SPNs:
 http/wfehostname domain\appoolaccount & mssqlsvc/sqlhostname (without service account, as apparently the previous admin got it to work for SP2010 Kerberos that way)

I also have an application server in between, but my sources tell me I should only create SPNs for web app pools, is that correct?

The WebApp is configured correctly.

Comment: Is the "wfehostname" you mention the exact URL users are using? Otherwise, don't forget the http/fully.qualified.url too. Only SPNs for web applications is indeed correct.

Comment: for just authenticating to SharePoint you don't need an SPN for the SQL server, only when delegating

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: Apparently it was a SPN issue after all. Because all guides said to add the SPN http/hostname I used the machine's actual hostname, which didn't work. I used the DNS domain and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thomas to check the SPN.

I made a post recently on some common Kerberos resources:  http://steve.thelineberrys.com/resources-for-setting-up-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint/

One of the resources I list there is called Delegconfig.  You can setup this tool as a website on your farm and then change your iis settings so that your sharepoint site points to the delegconfig website instead.  Then go to your url and the delegconfig site will test your kerberos configuration and tell you what is wrong.

I was banging my head against the wall for days trying to get kerberos working one time and this website tool was what lead me to the issue.  It turns out that my infrastructure guy misspelled our company name on the spn...